# How to upgrade Gentoo to use the latest versions of all installed software, including those with blank keywords?

Tags: gentoo, portage

I know how to upgrade Gentoo to use the latest version of all installed software marked with the testing keyword, namely by editing the `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` line in `/etc/portage/make.conf` to:

```
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~ARCH"
```

where `ARCH` is the architecture of the system, e.g. amd64 for x86-64 systems. This question is instead how to use the latest versions of all software that is in the presently-enabled overlays, including those with empty keyword fields. For example [`sys-devel/gcc-7.1.0-r1`](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sys-devel/gcc/gcc-7.1.0-r1.ebuild) presently has this keywords field in its ebuild:

```
KEYWORDS=""
```

I know it is marked with no keywords because it is experimental and may cause system breakage. I know this upgrade may cause system breakage so I have been warned but I just want to know how do I upgrade to a Gentoo experimental system (where a Gentoo 'testing' system would have the `~ARCH` keyword) with the latest available versions of all installed software.

EDIT: I thought I made myself clear by having "all installed software" in the title of this question but by the first comment I apparently did not. I want to upgrade ALL installed software to the very latest, including those marked with empty keywords fields.

Comment: Add a line `sys-devel/gcc` to the file `/etc/portage/package.accept_keywords` (create this file if not present).

Comment: I know how to do it on a package-by-package basis I mean all packages (which I did say in the title of this question, "of all installed software") I want to upgrade to the very latest.

Comment: You could try `*/*` pattern, but I bet there will be some unresolved dependencies in such extreme case.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following file (as jimmij suggested to you):

`/etc/portage/package.accept_keywords`

In said file, add an entry like so (comments added for explanation, reasoning below example file):

```
# The following values are permitted for arch:
# ** indicates a package with no keywords.  These are the 
# packages usually hard masked.
# ~arch, where arch is your platform type, will download testing versions.
# arch, where arch is your platform type, will download stable versions.
# This is the convention used in make.conf.

#Package Name            #Arch
sys-devel/gcc            **
package-cat/package      arch_keyword

# It's also acceptable to version lock a package.  
# Note that the arch is also needed, when a package has
# no keywords, or is in testing.

#Package Name                  #Arch
=sys-devel/gcc-6.3.0           **
<=sys-devel/gcc-3.4.6-r2       amd64
=package-cat/package-9999      **
```

Upgrading to the bleeding edge in the way your asking is only possible using the method jimmij and I are proposing, due to the fact **that not every package in Gentoo's tree has a hard-masked package or a 9999 package**. For this reason there is no way to globally keyword your system using `make.conf`.

---

The closest you'll get is is to use `app-portage/layman` to add and manage overlays, then add each package that has a masked version to `package.accept_keywords`, and then create a custom profile using your keywords file.  Lastly, use `eselect profile` to switch to your custom profile.  For an example of how to do this properly visit [Sabayon Linux](https://www.sabayon.org/), and the [Sabayon GitHub repository](https://github.com/Sabayon/).  The GitHub repository contains multiple overlays that turn a vanilla Gentoo Installation into a full fledged Linux Distribution with it's own package manager.  See also [ChromiumOS](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os), which uses a customized Gentoo Tree to build Chrome and ChromeOS for ChromeBooks.  Note that the tree is internal to Google.